# How can I add more collections in this model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to add another collection in order to perform simple CRUD operations.Also to add more collections if need be.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
description: String,
published: Boolean
},
{
collection: 'Tutorials',

timestamps: true

});
//If you use this app with a front-end that needs id field instead of _id,
// you have to override toJSON method that map default object to a custom object
schema.method("toJSON", function() {
const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
object.id = _id;
return object;
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Tutorial', schema);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make 'collection' contain multiple values? like an array?

Comment: also... there's some strange things going on with brackets in your schema, are the brackets above 'collection' suppose to be there?

Comment: i want to have multiple collections in the schema.For instance :users,products,categories etc.Thanks for highlighting the brackets mistake

Comment: Oh, so you mean to use the same schema but for different mongo collections? rather than creating multiple schemas?

Comment: Yeah exactly that.Can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now understanding your question is actually asking how you can use 1 schema for multiple collections, you can try this:

If your Schema looks like the following:

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    published: Boolean,
    timestamps: true
});
```

You can then change your export (at the bottom of your model) to look like:

```
var tutorials = mongoose.model('Tutorials', schema);
var users = mongoose.model('Users', schema);
var products = mongoose.model('Products', schema);
module.exports = {
    tutorials : tutorials,
    users : users, 
    products: products
}
```

*Above you can add what you like.*

Then when it comes to accessing each one individually, you can import them like so:

```
var tutorials = require('../models/schema').tutorials;
var users = require('../models/schema').users;
...
```

Comment: Thankyou,Let me try your explanation

Comment: @edwin  ok, after you check, please accept this if it has answered your question.

Comment: Hi @Jame,  did try your formulation but didn't work for my problem.Here is a repo of my project https://github.com/edwin001-tech/comtra-api--v2        navigate to /comtra.model.js  , to /comtra.controller.js, and finally to comtra.routes.js...........Again thanks!

Comment: @edwin you haven't followed what I have above? Also in your code, you're not using the same schema, it looks like you're trying to make multiple schemas - which goes against your question. Do your collections have the same schema (i.e same fields)?

Comment: Sorry @james, I sent a wrong commit.I did as you said and it worked like charm.THANKYOU!